# Messages don't get printed on the server side - sockets

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying this on Linux and I'm new to sockets in C language, I did create a client and a server in C, it works well when i send a single message, but when i loop it to get a continues chat, the messages don't get printed on the server side excluding the first message , I'm trying to this on the local host
here is the client code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#include<netinet/in.h>

int main(){
char msg[30] = {0};
struct sockaddr_in server;
struct sockaddr_in *ptr= &server;

int socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(socket_fd < 0){
    perror("socket");
    return 1;
}

ptr -> sin_family = AF_INET;
ptr -> sin_port = htons(10000);
ptr -> sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

int con = connect(socket_fd,(struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
if(con < 0){
    perror("connect");
    return 1;
}
do{
    memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
    fputs("client : ",stdout);
    fgets(msg, sizeof(msg), stdin);
    if(send(socket_fd, msg, sizeof(msg), 0) < 0){
            perror("send");
            return 1;
    }
    if(strncmp(msg, "!quit", 5) == 0)
        break;

    memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
    if(recv(socket_fd ,msg, sizeof(msg), 0) < 0){
            perror("recv");
            return 1;
    }
    printf("server : %s\n",msg);

}while(strncmp(msg,"!quit", 5) != 0);

puts("connection closed!");

close(socket_fd);

return 0;
```

}

and here is the server code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#include<netinet/in.h>
int main(){
char msg[100] = {0};
struct sockaddr_in server;
struct sockaddr_in *ptr = &server;

int server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if(server_socket < 0){
    perror("socket");
    return 1;
}

ptr-> sin_family = AF_INET;
ptr-> sin_port = htons(10000);
ptr-> sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

if(bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) < 0){
    perror("bind");
    return 1;
}

if(listen(server_socket, 1) < 0){
    perror("listen");
    return 1;
}

int client_socket;

if((client_socket = (accept(server_socket, NULL, NULL))) < 0){
    perror("accept");
    return 1;
}
do{
    memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
    if(recv(client_socket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0) < 0){
        perror("recv");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("client : %s\n",msg);
    if(strncmp(msg, "!quit", 5) == 0)
        break;

    memset(msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
    fputs("server : ",stdout);
    fgets(msg, sizeof(msg), stdin);
    if(send(client_socket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0) < 0){
        perror("send");
        return 1;
    }
}while(strncmp(msg, "!quit", 5) != 0);

puts("connection closed!");
close(client_socket);
close(server_socket);
return 0;
```

}

also if you have any have any tips about sockets, best practice, speed .... i will be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the server you are using `msg` as 100 bytes buffer. So when you call

```
send(client_socket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0)
```

you are sending 100 bytes but in the client side you are calling `recv` for the buffer the size of which is 30 bytes, so you need to call `recv` 4 times to read 100 bytes: `30 + 30 + 30 + 10`. You can fill `msg` buffer at the server side to `a`:

```
memset(msg, 'a', sizeof(msg));
fputs("server : ",stdout);
fgets(msg, sizeof(msg), stdin);
if(send(client_socket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0) < 0){
```

and now if you start both programs you will see something like this:

```
Client             | Server
-----------------------------------------
send `request1`    |  
                   | got `request1`
                   | send 'response1'
got 'response1'    |
send 'request2'    |
                   | got 'reguest2'
                   | send 'response2'
!!!!               | 
got `aaaaaaaaa...` |
got `aaaaa'        |
after first 100 B  |
were read you can  |
see response2 here |
```

by filling all bytes to `a` you can see that data are receiving until 100 bytes are read at the client side. When buffer is filled by NULL bytes, you cannot see message because NULL bytes for printf means the end of string (message was read, but you cannot see it if first byte the printf function takes is NULL byte).

Use `strlen` and change the call of `send` to:

```
send(client_socket, msg, strlen(msg), 0)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^ returns the length of entered message
```

Comment: it worked, thank you so much, too bad I can't upvote because my reputation is less than 15